# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer Orientation Dilemna

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't understand something with setting an AVCaptureVideo orientation. If I use:

`captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;` - I receive a warning saying that this method is deprecated in iOS 6.0.

So I use this:

`[[captureVideoPreviewLayer connection]setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];`- running fine in iOS 6.0 but crashing in iOS < 6.0.

What to do in order to be compatible with as much iOS as possible? Do you think it is a clean solution?

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")){
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
else{
    [[captureVideoPreviewLayer connection] setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft];
}
```

Thanks in advance!